# SignalR - dynamic URL?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have published my SignalR service on URL `http://localhost/signalr`

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.sendMsg(name, message);
    }
}
```

I need to restrict any calls to the service, that the URL must have some unique ID, e.g. `http://localhost/signalr/123` and then I can Invoke the `Send` method.

So, is there a posibility to use something like the URL routing here ? And, how can I obtain that ID before I step into that method ?

Answer (score 1):

The URL's in SignalR requests only apply to the initial setup calls. Those initial setup request paths are formatted by the SignalR library, but you can add query string parameters to the SignalR requests. Do this by adding the following line of code in your client Javascript before you call $.connection.hub.start.

```
$.connection.hub.qs = { 'X-UniqueID': 123 };
```

Then, to authorize a connection based on that special ID you would do custom auth for the SignalR hub (note that Microsoft's article on this topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization is lacking a lot of info, however I've posted a comment at the bottom with the necessary info on how to get it done). You accomplish this in the following way:

1) Add a class to your project called CustomAuthAttribute and inherit from Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.AuthorizeAttribute, giving the class the necessary decorations.

2) Override the AuthorizeHubConnection method and validate the request based on the query string.

3) You also may override AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation to check each and every web socket request.

4) Decorate your Hub class with the CustomAuth tag.

In the end your class may look like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
{
    if (request.QueryString["X-UniqueID"] == "123")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubContext, bool appliesToMethod)
{
    return true; // or do some validation
}
```

And your hub should look like this:

```
[CustomAuth]
public class myHub : Hub //Or some other name
```

Now if you're actually setting some sort of unique ID on every web socket call then you'll have to manually set the parameter on every call from the client. The approach I gave you is how to restrict or allow a connection itself. However, if you want to allow the connection and then restrict calls to specific methods you may use this approach as well. You can set the required data on the query string and then reference back to the original connection context from within AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation.

However, if you're using this for authentication/authorization I can't really tell you whether your scheme is secure or not. That all depends on how you have everything else set up. I can just tell you that this is how you can do custom auth.

What I actually do in my own code is to save user data in the HttpContext.Current.Items collection of the connect request (because I'm using IIS System.Web) and then access it on the AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation, because the HttpContext.Current.Items collection is still accessible for the duration of the connection.